# How to put several paths in CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH?

Tags: cmake

How can I have several paths for cmake to look for needed libraries. I installed zlib and libpng under `/usr/local/zlib` and `/usr/local/libpng` however, what I'm currently doing is first `cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/local/zlib`, then issuing a second command `cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/local/libpng" in order for cmake to recognize both.
Is there a way to have both paths in the same variable?

I tried `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/local/zlib:/usr/local/libpng` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to use `;` character instead of `:` to define lists.